# volatile under the hood

Tags: c, embedded, volatile

I would like some help please to better understand a part of the following passage:
"The volatile keyword qualifier indicates that the variable can be changed outside of the program.For example, an external device may write data to a port. Compilers will sometimes temporarily use a cache, or register, to hold the value in a memory location for optimization purposes. If the external write modifies the memory location,then this change will not be reflected in the cached or register value." 
(It comes from the book: understanding and using c pointers, pg 178-179)

The ambiguity i have is between these phrases: "to hold the value in **a** memory location" and "If the external write modifies the memory location".

My problem is: I get the impression that if an external device writes data to port, that data will be stored to some location (???), then they will be stored to the register/cache (??) and then inside the variable of the c language source code. Something is  misunderstood by me. From what i know the normal workflow should be: external device->small temporary buffer ->variable in RAM memory,(when data are going from a gadget to the MCU's RAM)

```
#define PORT 0xB0000000
unsigned int volatile * const port = (unsigned int*) PORT;
*port = 0x0BF4; // write to port
value = *port; // read from port
```

Comment: It is talking about *memory-mapped* devices. So from the program point of view everything is "memory".

Comment: What's the MCU you are using? As @EugeneSh.

Comment: Note: don't use the standard integer types for peripheral registers. Always use fixed-width types, see `stdint.h`. Wrt your text: it is not clear what you are asking. Maybe you should first think what your actualy problem is. Maybe you ask the question to the book author; we are not good at interpreting the intentions of people not related to stack overflow.

Comment: What's the MCU you are using? As @EugeneSh. says, a lot of a MCUs have devices that are memory mapped then, in C/C++, you have to write/read it by using pointers of an appropriate type (dimension). Some of these mapped memory areas might contain values different from those you write in it. This is due to various kind of behaviour of the devices. For example you might see that reading a memory-mapped device you obtains some status-bit while writing it you obtain the device will accomplish specific actions.

Answer (score 5):

[Memory mapped I/O devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O) don't go through the CPU core's registers (or cache, typically). That's why they're *external*, they just hang somewhere on the memory bus, pretending to be memory.

So values from such a device will appear directly in what (to the CPU) looks like memory.

In the example you gave, this:

```
*port = 0x0BF4; // write to port
```

could perhaps cause an A/D converter to start a conversion, and this

```
value = *port; // read from port
```

could read in the resulting value. This is *not* a very typical design (A/D converters tend to be a bit more complicated than that, and so on) but it's possible.

If a compiler thought "hey, that there is just a read from a location to which this value was written" it might replace the two statements with

```
value = 0x0BF4; // "optimized", but broken since no more I/O occurs
```

This would ruin your day, if you were trying to read values from that A/D converter.

Declaring the location `volatile` tells the compiler to not make any assumptions about the side-effects of accesses to the location.

If you look at something like an STM32F4 ARM-based microcontroller, it has tons of memory-mapped I/O (serial ports, USB controller, Ethernet, timers, A/D and D/A converters, ... they're all there) plus a bunch of internal (to the core, but still memory-mapped) things.

Comment: On most compilers the `volatile` qualifier will, in practice, seldom be needed for memory-mapped ports which are accessed by casting integer constants to pointers.  It's far more likely to matter when using variables which are accessed both in the main-line and in interrupt service routine.

Comment: @supercat Okay, perhaps, but surely the proper thing is to declare things as `volatile` where you really want the semantics of `volatile`, rather than relying on an assumption about how "most compilers" act? Working and correct is better than working.

Comment: It's certainly good to know the kinds of nonsense modern compilers pull, but I also think it's useful to understand from a historical context that when the keyword was added to the language compilers intended for embedded and systems programming only needed it to handle cases like interrupt-controlled flags.  The authors of the Standard deliberately refrained from requiring that all implementations be suitable for embedded and systems programming; the fact that it allows a compiler to do something does not imply that a compiler intended for any particular purpose, should.

Comment: BTW, if code has observed that `(uintptr_t)&someOrdinaryVariable` equals 0x12345678, would the lvalue expression `*(unsigned char*)0x12345678` be a legitimate way of accessing that variable?  The Standard would seem to offer a little leeway since it only requires that a pointer-to-integer round trip yield a pointer that compares equal to the original, and not one that's actually useful for any purpose other than comparison, but I would tend to think any compiler that can't guarantee that if `x==(uintptr_t)P`, then `(typeofP)x` will yield a pointer which is equivalent to p, shouldn't...

Comment: ...define `uintptr_t` at all [it's an optional type, and I don't really see much use to having the type if integer-to-pointer conversions won't yield useful semantics].

Answer (score 4):

As stated by others, these are items that are external to the CPU core itself, it could be ram it could be a memory mapped peripheral (a uart status register lets say or a timer register, etc).

```
#define SOME_STATUS_REGA  (*((volatile unsigned int *)0x10008000))
void fun ( void )
{
    while(SOME_STATUS_REGA==0) continue;
}
#define SOME_STATUS_REGB  (*((unsigned int *)0x10008000))
void more_fun ( void )
{
    while(SOME_STATUS_REGB==0) continue;
}
```

with one target and toolchain produces

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e59f200c    ldr r2, [pc, #12]   ; 14 <fun+0x14>
   4:   e5923000    ldr r3, [r2]
   8:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
   c:   0afffffc    beq 4 <fun+0x4>
  10:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  14:   10008000    andne   r8, r0, r0

00000018 <more_fun>:
  18:   e59f300c    ldr r3, [pc, #12]   ; 2c <more_fun+0x14>
  1c:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
  20:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
  24:   112fff1e    bxne    lr
  28:   eafffffe    b   28 <more_fun+0x10>
  2c:   10008000    andne   r8, r0, r0
```

you can see with the more_fun, not volatile case it reads the location one time does the comparison one time but goes into an infinite loop.  The compiler has done what we told it to do since there is no way that variable can change there is no reason to burn clock cycles re-reading something that wont change so if it wasnt zero the first and only read it will never be zero so this falls into an infinite loop.

If you make it volatile you are "asking" the compiler to read or write it every time your code accesses it.  Which you can see in the fun case, it goes back every time through the loop to read that address to see if it has changed.  The volatile keyword is what made the difference between these two behaviors.

It doesnt have to be hardware that changes these values, if you use a global variable to communicate between an isr and foreground code then that variable in memory can be changed by the isr and/or by the foreground code so both need to treat it as volatile.

You also have the case of a multicore/multithreaded processor where each core/thread independently has access to shared resources.  Not only do you need to use a volatile in that situation but you might need to have that ram not cached if the cores do not share the same cache and may have to have hardware and/or software locking if atomic operations are needed (ldrex/strex in the ARM world are the first step for that).

EDIT

Another demonstration, the problem is not only with reads, but with writes as well.  Lets say you have a peripheral that you need to write a config register to setup some mode, then you write it again to enable it with that mode.  or you have a hardware interface where each write increments some logic pointer and you do a series of writes to do something.

```
#define SOMETHING1 (*((volatile unsigned char *)0x10002000))
void fun ( void )
{
    SOMETHING1=5;
    SOMETHING1=5;
    SOMETHING1=6;
}
#define SOMETHING2 (*((unsigned char *)0x10002000))
void more_fun ( void )
{
    SOMETHING2=5;
    SOMETHING2=5;
    SOMETHING2=6;
}
```

without volatile, that peripheral is not going to operate properly.  The multiple writes to the same pointer/address are considered dead code and optimized out.

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e3a02005    mov r2, #5
   4:   e3a01006    mov r1, #6
   8:   e59f300c    ldr r3, [pc, #12]   ; 1c <fun+0x1c>
   c:   e5c32000    strb    r2, [r3]
  10:   e5c32000    strb    r2, [r3]
  14:   e5c31000    strb    r1, [r3]
  18:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  1c:   10002000    andne   r2, r0, r0

00000020 <more_fun>:
  20:   e3a02006    mov r2, #6
  24:   e59f3004    ldr r3, [pc, #4]    ; 30 <more_fun+0x10>
  28:   e5c32000    strb    r2, [r3]
  2c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  30:   10002000    andne   r2, r0, r0
```

EDIT2

Clang/llvm demonstrates the problem as well

```
#define A (*((volatile unsigned char *)0x10002000))
void afun ( void )
{
    A = 4;
    A = 5;
    A = 6;
    A |= 1;
    while(A==0) continue;
}
#define B (*((unsigned char *)0x10002000))
void bfun ( void )
{
    B = 4;
    B = 5;
    B = 6;
    B |= 1;
    while(B==0) continue;
}
```

Producing

```
00000000 <afun>:
   0:   e3a00a02    mov r0, #8192   ; 0x2000
   4:   e3a01004    mov r1, #4
   8:   e3800201    orr r0, r0, #268435456  ; 0x10000000
   c:   e5c01000    strb    r1, [r0]
  10:   e3a01005    mov r1, #5
  14:   e5c01000    strb    r1, [r0]
  18:   e3a01006    mov r1, #6
  1c:   e5c01000    strb    r1, [r0]
  20:   e5d01000    ldrb    r1, [r0]
  24:   e3811001    orr r1, r1, #1
  28:   e5c01000    strb    r1, [r0]
  2c:   e5d01000    ldrb    r1, [r0]
  30:   e3510000    cmp r1, #0
  34:   0afffffc    beq 2c <afun+0x2c>
  38:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

0000003c <bfun>:
  3c:   e3a00a02    mov r0, #8192   ; 0x2000
  40:   e3a01007    mov r1, #7
  44:   e3800201    orr r0, r0, #268435456  ; 0x10000000
  48:   e5c01000    strb    r1, [r0]
  4c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

Adding the volatile wont hurt you if you are doing onesy twosy things that are not in a domain that can optimize them out.  (a single write to each register in some sequence, a single read of a register, single also implying no loops).  It will most definitely hurt you if you are doing more than one write (which often happens when configuring a peripheral) doing a read modify write (x |= something, y &= something, z ^= something, etc).

If you are using a toolchain that doesnt have an optimizer or you choose not to optimize you wont have this problem, but that code is not portable if you leave the volatiles off, you will eventually run into trouble if you dont habitually deal with variables/code that crosses compile or other similar domains (hardware is a separate compile domain from software).

Comment: It is kind of like your mailbox.  If you did not put anything in the mailbox yourself do you have a reason to walk out there and check it?  Are there other parties that can modify the contents of the mailbox?  Now take something like the contents of your pocket if you did not modify the contents of your pocket do you need to check your pocket to see if something has changed or do you just know (assuming your memory or habits are such that this works)?  The mailbox is volatile your pocket is ideally not although for some of us...

Comment: I don't think `volatile` is for memory-mapped I/O so much as it is for interrupt-driven flags.  I/O addresses are often the direct result of integer-to-pointer casts, and many compilers would--at least historically--make no effort to cache such things.  Since caching the value of things like `*((unsigned char*)0xD000)` would require more work than caching things that have symbol table entries and would likely break code, such things were almost always exempt from caching, with or without `volatile`.

Comment: I just demonstrated it, gnu most definitely has this problem as do many others.  And the most common place where you are going to see volatile is in the endless number of register definitions for microcontrollers and other bare metal based libraries.   Sometimes thousands to tens of lines of code volatile pointer blah address...

Comment: There are probably even more thousands of lines that define registers at numeric addresses without using `volatile` since many compilers don't try to register-cache numbered addresses with or without the qualifier.  Adding "volatile" to every entry in a header file would make it bigger, slow down compilation, and on many compilers serve no purpose.  Further, the primary case where compilers could benefit from caching hardware registers would be best served by adding qualifiers which distinguish the semantics of writes, reads whose value is used, and reads whose value is ignored.

Comment: you are welcome to add to your example demonstrations of this, gnu definitely has the problem, trivial to demonstrate, at this point in time I sadly dont use others except perhaps clang which I could create an example for.

Comment: Many hardware registers and interrupt-control flags will change some external aspect of system state when written, but will behave as ordinary RAM when read.  Many others may appear to change spontaneously, but wouldn't care if code that reads them and ignores their value were omitted.  An ability to optimize those usage patterns via suitable directives would often offer more real-world benefit than one which tries to consolidate accesses to numbered addresses without qualifiers.

Comment: Please demonstrate.  I showed it is clear that not just interrupt status registers are needed, simply initializing a peripheral may require volatiles.  The list of maybes and the situations you are talking about dont change the code with and without the volatile so the safe bet is go with all the time.  Doesnt do any harm for the situations you are talking but prevents failure for the situations where it matters.

Comment: There are many places the Standard invites compiler writers to use judgment in deciding what behaviors make the most sense given an implementations' target plaform, application field, and corpus of existing code.  For some reason around 1997 the Standard has been reinterpreted as an invitation to throw judgment out the window.  Safe programming practices today require that programmers defend against compiler obtuseness in ways that weren't necessary in the past, but it's not because there was anything wrong with the older practices.  Instead, it's because compiler writers...

Comment: ...see some virtue in showing that code which targets implementations that are suitable for some purpose won't work on those which are deliberately made less suitable for that purpose.  I'd be hard-pressed to think of situations where the benefits of full read-write caching optimizations for unqualified integer-constant addresses would justify the extra effort and compile time necessary to support that.  Can you think of any?

Comment: There is essentially no extra effort to add the volatile, defining addresses to external resources in this way is a sad to see habit based on the behaviors of compiler writers today, no reason it has to work tomorrow, but you will fail if you dont copy the habits of the current array of chip vendors code today.  The habits are now changing even more for the worse by using unions and structs to point across compile domains at these external resources.  That one fails faster/sooner than the volatile trick.  I was trained to and continue to avoid these and other bad habits.

Comment: Yet the poster asked the question and a very high percentage of MCU programmers are going to use this code or just take on faith these habits as gospel not understanding that they are an interpretation of the language, and can stop working on the next compiler or compiler version.

Comment: At the same time the compilers have had a tendency to be consistent specifically with the volatile keyword.  And as demonstrated it is trivial to see what your compiler does right now, using a volatile wont hurt you, but will not using it with X compiler for Y target hurt you right now.

Comment: Note relying on the standard is the same mistake as relying on the current habits of a compiler.   In order to produce reliable and/or portable code, either avoiding areas that compilers tend to be wishy washy on or building yourself a set of tools or defenses (test the feature before you use it.  Check the size of a struct before you use it across a compile domain, etc.  Not only is the volatile working to produce all the actions I asked for but is the compiler generating the right instruction, if I asked for a 16 bit load or store is it actually doing that, etc.

Comment: Or pick a different language, something way more rigid ADA, Pascal, etc.  One whose spec (not that those have a spec, probably dont) is not loaded with implementation defined answers like C has.

Comment: The Standard makes no effort to require that implementations be suitable for any particular purpose.  If a program needs to use DMA to send some data of mixed arbitrary types, which should be a more efficient approach: (1) use `memcpy` to move it to a buffer and then use `volatile` stores to trigger the DMA controller; (2) copy the data into a `volatile`-qualified buffer, reading a character at a time to avoid running afoul of aliasing rules, and then use a `volatile` store to start DMA, or (3) use `memcpy` to copy the data to a non-qualified `uint64_t[]`, then manually copy that...

Comment: ...to a `volatile`-qualified buffer, and then use a `volatile` store to start the DMA.  I'd suggest that a quality implementation suitable for embedded programming should make it easy for programmers to use #1 with confidence, and without having to embed compiler-specific directives in code.  Saying that the only way to have a compiler ever treat something as `volatile` is to order that the compiler *always* treat it as variable, even if 99% of the time it wouldn't need to be, doesn't seem conducive to optimization.

Comment: Also, from the point of view of the Standard, a compiler is under no more obligation to regard `*(unsigned char volatile*)0xD400=5;` as a command to store a byte with value 5 to hardware address 0xD400 than it would be to regard `*(unsigned char*)0xD400=5;` as such an command.  A conforming compiler could specify that the only integers which can be converted to non-trap pointer values are those received by pointer-to-integer conversions.  Consequently, practically *all* embedded code has to rely upon features defined by convention and precedent rather than the Standard.

Answer (score 1):

Before C added the "volatile" keyboard, every access to an object that didn't have a `register` qualifier would result in a load from or store to at object's address.  Given the declatations `int i,j;`, the code:

```
i+=j;
j+=i;
i+=j;
```

would load `i` and `j` from memory, add them, and store the result to `i`.  It would then load `i` and `j` from memory again, add them, and store the result to `j`.  Finally, it would load `i` and `j` from memory a third time, add them, and store the result to `i`.  Three statements would thus result in six loads, three adds, and three stores.

If there isn't anything "special" about `i` and `j`, something like the following will be more efficient:

```
register int t1,t2;
t1=i; t2=j;
t1+=t2; t2+=t1; t1+=t2;
i=t1; j=t2;
```

While that looks like more code, operations on `t1` and `t2` don't require loads and stores.  Thus, the compiler will only have to generate two loads, three adds, and two stores--saving the costs of four loads and a store compared with the original.

Having a compiler automatically turn the former kind of code into the latter would be helpful save for one problem: sometimes things that look like variables may be changed in ways the compiler doesn't know about.  This can happen either because circuitry other than memory is wired onto the memory bus (many systems have I/O devices which are wired to respond when code tries to read or write certain addresses), or because a machine may respond to external stimuli by dispatching control to a special section of code called an interrupt handler and then resuming whatever it was doing when the interrupt handler returns.  Interrupt handlers often read and write variables which may also be accessed by main-line code (indeed, that's one of the reasons they exist) but if code does something like:

```
while(!data_received)
  ;
```

and relies upon an interrupt handler setting data_received once data has become available, such code might fail if the compiler replaces it with:

```
t1 = data_received;
while(t1)
  ;
```

which would execute the loop "faster", but would fail to exit the loop when data arrives.

The purpose of `volatile` is to tell the compiler that certain objects require "special" treatment.  Some compilers (the sensible ones, IMHO) will interpret `volatile` as an indication that accessing the object thus marked might arbitrarily affect everything in the system in ways the compiler doesn't know about, thus allowing constructs like:

```
extern volatile char * volatile dma_mem;
extern volatile unsigned dma_count, dma_command, dma_busy;

void put_data(char *data, unsigned size)
{
  dma_mem = data;
  dma_count = size;
  // Following will trigger hardware to automatically copy "dma_count"
  // bytes from memory starting at "dma_mem"; dma_busy will read as
  // zero once operation is complete.
  dma_command = OUTPUT_MEMORY; // Exact value depends on ardware
  while(dma_busy)
    ;
}
```

On a compiler which refrains from keeping anything in registers across a `volatile` access, a function like the above can be used to output data from "ordinary" memory provided that all external accesses are complete before the function returns.  If a compiler keeps things in registers even across `volatile` accesses in the name of optimization, however, such code may fail unless the the buffer into which the data is put is also qualified `volatile`.

PS--while `volatile` can be and often is used for I/O accesses, it often shouldn't(*) be needed nearly as much for those as for things which are affected by interrupts.  In many cases, I/O addresses would be defined using constructs like

```
#define PORTA (*(unsigned char*)0xD000)
#define PORTB (*(unsigned char*)0xD002)
```

and while the Standard wouldn't require a compiler to treat such addresses as volatile, many compilers would do so anyway because programmers' use of such addresses implies that they know things the compilers don't.  By contrast, flags that get set by interrupt handlers look to the compiler like ordinary RAM, and it's only the `volatile` flag that would indicate that there's anything special about them.

(*) I've seen a lot of vendor-supplied header files which don't use `volatile` for I/O addresses.  If a compiler will generate the same code with or without that keyword, adding more verbiage for the compiler to chew through on every build will slow down compilation for no purpose.  *The authors of the Standard deliberately refrained from requiring that all compilers be suitable for embedded or systems programming, and thus made no effort to forbid behaviors that would make compilers unsuitable for such purposes*.  Code for a particular purpose should only be expected to work on compilers that are suitable for such purpose; if such code fails on a compiler that is deliberately made less suitable for that purpose, that doesn't mean the code is "broken"--instead it means the compiler is no longer suitable for use with such code.

PS--For a compiler to make any useful optimizations based upon a constant address not being `volatile`, it would have to either "know" that no other object had been observed as having that same address, or else allow for the possibility that even if two integers x and y are equal, `*(uint8_t*)x` and `*(uint8_t)y` a write to one might not be recognized as affecting the other.  Since the Standard says that round-tripping a pointer to an integer and back yields something which "compares equal" to the original pointer, but doesn't say it can actually be used for any purpose, that would be conforming but unexpected.

Consider, for example, the following program containing two separate translation units [assume required headers are included]

```
// UNIT ONE
extern unsigned char foo;
extern uintptr_t volatile tfoo;

int foo_addr(void)
{
   tfoo = (uintptr_t)&foo;
   return tfoo == 0x12345678;
}

// UNIT TWO
void foo_addr(void);
unsigned char foo;
uintptr_t volatile tfoo;
int main(void)
{
  int ok = foo_addr();
  foo = 2;
  if (ok)
    (unsigned char*)0x12345678 = 4;
  return ok + foo;
}
```

If `foo` happens not to have been given the address 0x12345678, no write will occur to address 0x12345678 and the code will return 0.  If the address of `foo` is 0x12345678, however, then `(unsigned char*)0x12345678` would be a legitimate pointer to `foo`, and a compiler should be required to recognize the access unless it decides that it doesn't feel like treating round-trip pointer-to-integer conversions as yielding usable pointers.

The easiest way, by far, to regard `(unsigned char*)0x12345678 as aliasing everything it would need to alias would be to treat it as`volatile`and refrain from caching in registers anything whose address has been exposed.  Useful optimizations from treating such a variable as not being`volatile` would be rare unless a compiler is willing to bend pointer semantics.